# Laravel unique field validation issue (Duplicate entry error)

Tags: php, database, laravel, validation, laravel-6

In my laravel app database I have a table called, apps

In that table, I have a column name,'domain'. Domain is an unique column.

**The Problem**

There is a form in my front end blade for user to create a new app. From that form user should first enter the sub domain name first and there is a drop down to select domain name.

Once the user enters the sub domain name and then select the domain name I merge the two inputs from my controller and then that merged value save in the 'domain' column.

Ex:
Sub domain name: ABC 
Domain name:TEST.SITE
Merged value (The value I save in the domain column):ABC.TEST.SITE

Now as my domain  is an unique when there is a duplicate value it throws me a laravel error saying duplicate entry.

But from my controller I couldn't validate the sub domain name input as at the end I'm saving the merged value.

Any Solution to fix this out and make the validation properly,

Here is the code for form.

```
<form id="appform" action="{{ route('app.save') }}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                            <input type="text" id="app-subdomainname" class="form-control" name="subDomainName" placeholder="{{ __('sentence.Sub Domain Name') }}" aria-required="true">
                         <br>
                            <select id="app-subdomainsuffix" class="form-control" name="subDomainSuffix" aria-required="true">
                                <option value="">- {{ __('sentence.Select domains') }} -</option>
                                <option value="TEST.SITE">TEST.SITE</option>
                            </select>

                        <br>

                        <select id="app-packagetype" class="form-control" name="packageType" aria-required="true">
                            <option value="">- {{ __('sentence.Select package type') }} -</option>
                            @foreach($packages as $package)
                            <option value="{{$package->id}}">{{$package->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                        </select>

                        <br>
                            <select id="app-payment" class="form-control" name="paymentoption" aria-required="true">
                            </select>

                        <br>

                            <select id="app-themeid" class="form-control" name="themeid" aria-required="true">
                                <option value="">- {{ __('sentence.Select theme') }} -</option>
                                <option value="default">Starter</option>
                            </select>

                        <br>
                            <select id="app-lang" class="form-control" name="lang" aria-required="true">
                                <option value="">- {{ __('sentence.Select Language') }} -</option>
                                <option value="en">English</option>
                                <option value="jp">Japanese</option>
                            </select>
                        <br>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">{{ __('sentence.Save') }}</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
```

My Controller (Only the data store function has been included)

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'subDomainName' => 'required',
            'subDomainSuffix' => 'required',
            //'package_type' => 'required',
            'lang' => 'required',
            'theme' => 'required',
            'paymentoption' => 'required',

        ]);

        $user = Auth::user();
        $fullDomain = $request->subDomainName.'.'.$request->subDomainSuffix;
        $credentials = $this->generateDbcredentials();
        App::create([
            'domain' => $fullDomain,
            'masterUserId' => $user->id,
            'dbName' => $credentials[0],
            'host' =>env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => $credentials[1],
            'password' => $credentials[2],
            'theme' => $request->themeid,
            'lang' =>  $request->lang,
            'status' => 1,
            'package_type' => $request->packageType,
            'payment_option' => $request->paymentoption,
            'isAppCreated' => 1,
            'isDefault' =>0,
        ]);
```

How can I do the validation properly

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of combining the input on the backend, could you use a hidden field to combine the input on the frontend and send the domain filed already concatenated? Then validating the value would be trivial

Comment: Another option would be to use a middleware to combine the two values into the "domain"  input var before the validation occurs

Comment: don't you think the hidden field method is unsecured?

Comment: I wouldnt think so, it would simply be combining the values from `subDomainName` and `subDomainSuffix` right? These fields are already present in the request, we'd just be combining them on the front end. Unless I missunderstand, or theres more to it than just this.

Comment: perfect, got it @WesleySmith

Comment: @WesleySmith thanks for the advise, did as you told(using a hidden field) and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following validation rule

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'subDomainName' => 'required',
    'subDomainSuffix' => 'required',
    //'package_type' => 'required',
    'lang' => 'required',
    'theme' => 'required',
    'paymentoption' => 'required',
    'domain'  => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('apps')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            return $query->whereDomain($request->subDomainName.'.'.$request->subDomainSuffix);
        }),
    ]
],
[
    'domain.unique' => __('messages.app.error.unique', [
        'subDomainName' => $request->subDomainName, 
        'subDomainSuffix' => $request->subDomainSuffix
    ]),
]);
```

Comment: While this approach would work, it also leads to doing the work of concatenating the values twice in two different places (here, then again in the backend code where its used). This can lead to increased maintenance keeping both places the same or bugs in the future if one place is updated but not the other . I would recommend against this approach for those reasons.

Answer (score 0):

first of all its always throws an error because of you are doing wrong with html element name and id please write in naming conversion rule

```
 'package_type' => 'required', worng with name.
```

```
 'theme' => 'required',wrong with name.
```

it never done validation you want.

your unique domain validation is here

```
'domain'  => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('apps')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->whereDomain($request->subDomainName.'.'.$request->subDomainSuffix);
    }),
]
```

this is error..

```
'domain.unique' => __('messages.app.error.unique', [
    'subDomainName' => $request->subDomainName, 
    'subDomainSuffix' => $request->subDomainSuffix
]),
```

i hope so its work if not tell me in comments